# Implement Suggestions & Spell check in full-text search Using Query builder in AEM

Tags: full-text-search, aem, query-builder, spell-checking, search-suggestion

While implementing full-text search Using Query builder in AEM-6.4, I need to add feature for spell check and suggestion.

Is there any way to implement this using **predicate map** properties in Query builder, Indexing etc

**Updated**:

Code snippet -

```
@Inject
private Suggester suggester;

final String[] suggetions = suggester.getSuggestions(session, "searchGlobal", queryString, true);
final String spellCheck = suggester.spellCheck(session, queryString);
```

**suggetions** - is returning empty value & 
**suggester.spellCheck(session, queryString)** - is throwing Nullpointer Exception

Answer (score 0):

AEM internally uses Jackrabbit Oak JCR implementation, which uses lucene indexing for repository.

If we look at [Jackrabbit Oak Lucene Index documentation](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/query/lucene.html#suggestions). We would need to do 2 steps

1. Create required index
2. Use query, for example below to use the suggestion index created above

> SELECT rep:suggest() FROM [nt:base] WHERE SUGGEST('test') AND ISDESCENDANTNODE('/a/b')

Similar way spell check can be also implemented, would just need property configured in index accordingly.

Comment: I don't wan to write query in SQL format, I need to create query using predicate maps. How will step 2 be implemented?

Comment: Not that I am aware of